# CSS3 slider with a challenging transformation, part2, re

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

**Update 2**
There are Next/Prev buttons now, but can't program them to show slides, yet.

**Update 1**
By using a radio button method I managed to position the images the way I wanted to - [prooflink](http://imageshack.com/a/img189/3431/g4fz.jpg).

Still having the following problems:

1) For some reason the central image is partially seen (thought locally with prefixfree.min.js everything looks fine), any ideas why?

2) Couldn't attach a link to the img of the central images and make it work, plz advise.

3) Any clues on how to attach Next/Prev buttons so they move the slides infinitely?

new and much better code:

1) http://jsfiddle.net/Goodnewstown/rvBS2/5/

HI there!
Having hard times figuring how to make a slider with an active enlarged image in the middle.
After pressing the right or left button comes the next image from the left of the right of the center respectively. Plus this image moves to the center and grows up to 300-400% and is a link to the correlated page. 
A link to what I mean by that -  imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1313x437q90/208/t12a.jpg
I am stuck near the start of all of this ;/

My HTML code:

```
<div class="SliderWrapper">
<a href="#" class="control_prev"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/89/fpc8.png" alt="Button left" width="102" height="102"></a>
<a href="#" class="control_next"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/7/1d36.png" alt="Button right" width="102" height="102"></a></div>
<div class="Slider">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/17/yqtu.png" alt="France small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/198/bl8i.png" alt="Russia small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/13/hxgg.png" alt="Germany small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>      
<li><a href="#"> <img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/585/pc91.png" alt="France small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/51/e624.png" alt="Russia small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/138/q3he.png" alt="Germany small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/837/4kzw.png" alt="Russia small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/c/440/iy3q.png" alt="Germany small" width="104" height="104"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
 .SliderWrapper {
    width: 1900px;
    height: 400px;}
    .Slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;}
    .Slider ul {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    list-style: none;}
    .Slider ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #ccc;}
    a.control_prev, a.control_next {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;}
    a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}
    a.control_prev {
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;} 
    a.control_next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;}
```

Comment: Run your code through a beautifier before posting here. No one will want to spend the time tidying up your code just to help you.

Comment: Surely I did, this wierd beautifier didnt let css code thru (btw from sublime). Where is that confidence comes from that no one at all, never say never ;) Thx for the help sorting the code though.

Comment: how about putting all the flags in one image (use one for the left side, one for the right side), then the arrows would move that pictures and change the center picture and link?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I'll try to code smth but it is quite vague for me to figure the center part out as the main image line is X height and the center part/image is Y height %)

Comment: Using a radio button method was quite helpful in my question. But there are still some big steps to take before its done.